# Azure Synapse - How to retrieve metadata info to generate my own CREATE TABLE statement via JDBC

Tags: java, azure, jdbc, ddl, azure-synapse

Is there a way to retrieve the list of distribution column(s) info from the Azure Synapse JDBC drivers? I can do most of it but stuck on the WITH DISTRIBUTION WITH clause(s) part at the bottom.

For example, I just need something basic to re-create a DDL like so:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE [type]='U' AND [name] = 'AZURE_TEST'
 AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo')
DROP TABLE [dbo].[AZURE_TEST]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AZURE_TEST] (
    BIGINT1                                     BIGINT                  NOT NULL,
    BOOLEAN1                                    BIT                     NOT NULL,
    BYTEINT1                                    TINYINT                 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED NOT ENFORCED,
    CHAR1                                       CHAR(1)                 NULL,
    CHAR2                                       CHAR(10)                NULL,
    CHARACTER_VARYING1                          VARCHAR(10)             NULL,
    CHARACTER1                                  CHAR(1)                 NOT NULL,
    CHARACTER2                                  CHAR(10)                NULL,
    DATE1                                       DATE                    NULL,
    DOUBLE_PRECISION1                           FLOAT(15)               NULL,
    INTEGER1                                    INTEGER                 NULL,
    INTERVAL1                                   VARCHAR(50)             NULL,
    NATIONAL_CHARACTER_VARYING2                 NVARCHAR(10)            NULL,
    NUMERIC1                                    NUMERIC(18, 0)          NULL,
    NUMERIC2                                    NUMERIC(10, 0)          NOT NULL,
    NUMERIC3                                    NUMERIC(10, 2)          NULL,
    REAL1                                       REAL                    NULL,
    SMALLINT1                                   SMALLINT                NULL,
    TIME1                                       TIME                    NULL,
    TIMESTAMP1                                  DATETIME2               NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [BIGINT1] ),
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the columns used for the DISTRIBUTION for a given table by running the next sql:

```
SELECT c.name FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.pdw_column_distribution_properties AS d ON t.object_id = d.object_id AND d.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE t.name = 'table_name' AND s.name = 'schema_name' AND d.distribution_ordinal <> 0;
```